# Golang HTTP POST using HTTP/1.0

Tags: http, go

Is it possible to send HTTP requests using HTTP/1.0 with golang?

I tried the following:

```
req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", url, buffer)
req.Proto = "HTTP/1.0"
client := &http.Client{}
resp, err = client.Do(req)
```

But it seems req.Proto is ignored. The message is sent out using HTTP/1.1.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently you can't. The `Request.Proto` field is ignored when making the request by the [`Client`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client).

Quoting from the doc of [`http.Request`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request):

```
// The protocol version for incoming requests.
// Client requests always use HTTP/1.1.
Proto      string // "HTTP/1.0"
```

> Client requests **always** use HTTP/1.1.